# Merge vertices and vertex order

Tags: mesh, vertices

When merging vertices,
it seems to blender deletes the newer vertex/vertices (= vertex/vertices with the larger index number) among targeted vertices,
and the oldest vertex is left,
and the relative order of the remained vertices of the object doesn't change.

Is this behavior guaranteed or can vary?

[image: verts to merge]
[image: merged result]